# changing strat_urls everytime on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to change strat_urls on scrapy.
I'm Japanese and I want to transltae English word. Using weblio that is English dictionary on Internet, I want to get means of word automatically with scrapy.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import logging
from elscrapy.items import ElscrapyItem
class WordSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'word'
    allowed_domains = ['ejje.weblio.jp']
    #start_urls = ['http://ejje.weblio.jp/']
  

    def __init__(self, query='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(WordSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/' + query]



    def parse(self, response):
        word=response.xpath('//*[@id="summary"]/div[2]/p/span[2]/text()').get()
        yield{
            'word':word
        }
```

I change start_urls everytime, by inputting word with command below.

```
scrapy crawl word -a query=relative
```

However, output is below or csv is null when csv's output command.

```
ERROR: Error processing {'word': '\n                比較上の、相対的な、相関的な、(…と)関係があって、関連して、(…に)呼応して、比例して、関係を示す、関係詞に導かれた'}
```

please tell me solution to ouput csv file

Comment: Can you show me a real example of query with full URL?
https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/x???

Answer (score 0):

I use string list for translation word input instead of argument passing.
I think it help to reduce a time than manual step.

You can change from *word list* to world list file if you need to many words translation.

First key point is **POST call** return **translated word** in **HTML**
I checked it by Postman with ***x-www-form-urlencoded*** in body as attached image.

Second key point is translated word or statement has different parsing it depend on original word input.
I use your examples from your question. Both types(word and statment) are works.

Find translated word by scrapping after request post call.

Inside Scrapy, request POST call with original word to the **weblio.jp**

1. POST call
   [image]
2. This is input words

```
words = ['比較上の','相対的な','(…と)関係があって', '関連して','(…に)呼応して','比例して','関係を示す','関係詞に導かれた']
```

3. This is scraping result

```
[
    {
        "word": "比較上の",
        "translate": "relative"
    },
    {
        "word": "(…に)呼応して",
        "translate": "in concert with…"
    },
    {
        "word": "比例して",
        "translate": "pro rata"
    },
    {
        "word": "相対的な",
        "translate": "relative"
    },
    {
        "word": "(…と)関係があって",
        "translate": "Be connected with each other (with ...)\n\nBe connected (with ...)"
    },
    {
        "word": "関係を示す",
        "translate": "I show relations"
    },
    {
        "word": "関連して",
        "translate": "in connection with"
    },
    {
        "word": "関係詞に導かれた",
        "translate": "I was led to the relative\n\nIt was derived by a relative"
    }
]
```

4. word.py - scrapy code

```
import scrapy
import urllib

class WordSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "word"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://translate.weblio.jp/'
        words = ['比較上の','相対的な','(…と)関係があって', '関連して','(…に)呼応して','比例して','関係を示す','関係詞に導かれた']
        for word in words:
            my_data = {
                'lp': 'JE',
                'lpf': 'JE',
                'tm': '72807',
                'tlt': 'english',
                'originalText': word
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                method='POST',
                body=urllib.parse.urlencode(my_data),
                headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # find original word
        word=response.css("textarea.contTAGb::text").get()

        # find translate word
        translate=response.css("div.transExpB ul li::text").get()
        if not translate:
            translate = ''
            # find translate statement
            translate=response.xpath('//input[@id="reTranslatedText"]').xpath('@value').get()
        yield{
            'word': word,
            'translate': translate
        }
```

5. setting.py - avoid robot.txt and can export Japanese characters.

```
BOT_NAME = 'word'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['word.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'word.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Run it from terminal

```
scrapy crawl word -o translate.json
```

6. If you want to opposite direction (English to Japanese )
   Use this POST option in body.

[image]